# How to send PDF converted from base64 through Intnet?

Tags: android, pdf, android-intent, base64

I've got the `pdf` file in `base64`, I decoded it, send through the `Intent` but unfortunately external apps can't read it (**Evernote** e.g. says that it can't open empty file). Another strange thing is that I have no such apps like **Adobe Reader** or **Messanger** in the list after conversion. This is my code:

```
FileOutputStream fos;
fos = context.openFileOutput("doc.pdf", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String fileB64 = url.split(",")[1];
byte[] decodedStr = Base64.decode(fileB64, Base64.NO_WRAP);
fos.write(decodedStr);
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
sendIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
File filePath = new File(String.valueOf(context.getFilesDir()));
File newFile = new File(filePath, "application/pdf");
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, context.getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".FileProvider", newFile));
sendIntent.setType("application/pdf");
context.startActivity(sendIntent);
fos.flush();
fos.close();
```

I also try the online converter to check if the conversion went OK. I've got something like this:

```
%PDF-1.3
3 0 obj
<</Type /Page
/Parent 1 0 R
/Resources 2 0 R
/MediaBox [0 0 348.00 256.00]
/Contents 4 0 R
>>
endobj
4 0 obj
<</Length 11287>>
stream
1.000 0.000 0.000 -1.000 0.000 256.000 cm
0.20 w
0 G
q
1.000 0.000 0.000 1.000 0.000 0.000 cm
q
/F9 16 Tf
/F9 12 Tf
q
q
Q
q
Q
Q
q
Q
q
/GS1 gs
1.000 0.000 0.000 1.000 0.000 0.000 cm
0.000 0.000 m 
348.000 0.000 l
348.000 0.000 348.000 0.000 348.000 0.000 c
348.000 256.000 l
348.000 256.000 348.000 256.000 348.000 256.000 c
0.000 256.000 l
```

To avoid answers like *"this is an image, why don't you send it as image"* I can tell you that it is just another option for my conversion. My conversion and sharing it as image works perfectly. Thanks for your time and for any help!

**@EDIT**

I changed this line:
 `File newFile = new File(filePath, "application/pdf");`
to this:
 `File newFile = new File(filePath, "doc.pdf");`

But now I got the blank page in pdf.

Comment: Make sure file is saving properly and try load file in webview if no other external apps available.

Comment: @SARATHV Well, there are apps available, as I said: Evernote or Gmail. They say: "can't read empty file". Did you read the post?

Comment: @SARATHV I did the same saving for image export and it works, why it should work wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Bug #1: You open a file, then attempt to hand it to another app before completing your work with the file (`flush()`, the missing `getFD().sync()`, and `close()`.

Bug #2: You are doing disk I/O on the main application thread.

Bug #3: You are attempting to read the entire decoded PDF into heap space, which will fail for many PDF files, as they will be too large.

Bug #4: `newFile` does not point to the file that you are attempting to create, but rather some file with `application/pdf` in the path. As a result, the other app has no way to access your PDF, even if it were completely written to disk.

Bug #5: You do not have `FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION` on the `Intent`, and so the third-party app may not have read access to your content (see the third bullet in [the docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html#Permissions)).

Comment: I did the same thing for the image, the only difference is `application/pdf` here. Why is that then? I mean Bug#4 mostly

Comment: @soommy12: `File newFile = new File(filePath, "application/pdf")`. I have no idea why you are putting a MIME type there. Your `openFileOutput()` call is using `"doc.pdf"`. I strongly recommend that you create a `File` object once and use it in both places: for writing the file (create a `FileOutputStream` on the `File`) and for getting your `Uri`.

Comment: Well, I just make use of your advice from my another post

Comment: Can you post some code please? I don't get what you're tying to tell me

Comment: @soommy12: Replace `File newFile = new File(filePath, "application/pdf")` with `File newFile = new File(filePath, "doc.pdf")`.

Comment: I did this see the uploaded question. Now I got blank pdf

Comment: @soommy12: I pointed out four bugs. You fixed one. I have now added a fifth bug. After you fix them all, if you still have problems, take a look at the actual file that you are writing and see if it has the correct content. If it does, your problem lies in the `FileProvider`. If it does not, your problem lies in how you obtaining the content and writing it to the file.

Comment: I've added this flag to my code earlier but it still doesn't work