# Intent sends blank PDF

Tags: android, pdf, android-intent

I am trying to send my pdf via email but the generated pdf is blank. I really have no idea why is that. The same method for images works perfectly. This is my code:

```
FileOutputStream fos;
fos = context.openFileOutput("doc.pdf", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String fileB64 = url.split(",")[1];
byte[] decodedStr = Base64.decode(fileB64, Base64.NO_WRAP);
fos.write(decodedStr);
fos.getFD().sync();
fos.flush();
fos.close();
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
sendIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK| Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
File filePath = new File(String.valueOf(context.getFilesDir()));
File newFile = new File(filePath, "doc.pdf");
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, context.getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".FileProvider", newFile));
sendIntent.setType("application/pdf");
context.startActivity(sendIntent);
```

In short: I generate the PDF but the whole page is blank (white). How to deal with that? Thanks for your help!

Comment: As we discussed in [the duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46115727/115145), take a look at the PDF file that you created and see if it has the correct content. If it does, your problem lies in the `FileProvider`, or perhaps in the PDF viewer app (which might have bugs). If the PDF file has the wrong content, your problem lies in the decode operation or how you are getting the value of `url`. BTW, usually, to view a PDF, you use `ACTION_VIEW`, not `ACTION_SEND`.

Comment: @CommonsWare I do not want to view it, I want to share it, that's why I use `ACTION_SEND`. IMHO it's not duplicate, here I got another problem.

Comment: @CommonsWare How to look at the PDF file while it is in internal storage?

Comment: See "Poking Around Internal Storage" in [this blog post](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html).